# Child Not Re-rendering on List Item Deletion in Parent but Adding to the List Item Triggering Re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have Simple Add and Delete to my List sample .. 
I made two child components

1. Lead Form  Component ( Which Add New Leads to the List )
2. Lead List Component ( Which Simply render Leads List also have delete button which trigger delete action by passing ID back to parent )

In parent ,  the.state.leads holds all the leads

on Form Submit .. it adds to the.state.leads and LEAD LIST CHILD Components 
successfully Re-Renders with new added lead

but on deleting list in the LEAD LIST  , The lead list not re renders

[Image ; Dev Tool Debug in the browser -React Console screenshot ..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpUQg.png)

MY LeadList Component 
.........................................................

```
class LeadList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      leads: this.props.avlList
    };
    this.handelDeleteLead = this.handelDeleteLead.bind(this);
  }

  handelDeleteLead(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.DeleteLead(e.target.id);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.leads);
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.leads.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              {item.name} - {item.mobile} -{item.active ? "Active" : "Inactive"}
              -
              <div
                id={item.id}
                onClick={this.handelDeleteLead}
                cursor="pointer"
              >
                X
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

......

My APP.js   Parent Componnet 
....................................

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      leads: [{ id: 1, name: "Panindra", mobile: "88842555542", active: true }]
    };
    this.handleAddToLeads = this.handleAddToLeads.bind(this);
    this.handleRemoveLeads = this.handleRemoveLeads.bind(this);
  }

  handleAddToLeads(lead) {
    let newleadsTemp = this.state.leads;
    lead.id = Math.random() * Math.random();

    newleadsTemp.push(lead);
    // assign a name of list to item list
    let newLeads = newleadsTemp;
    this.setState({
      leads: newLeads
    });
  }

  handleRemoveLeads(lead_id) {
    console.log(" Leads list before fitler ..." + this.state.leads);

    let newFitleredLeads = remove(this.state.leads, lead_id);
    this.setState({
      leads: newFitleredLeads
    });
    console.log(" Leads list after fitler ..." + this.state.leads);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1> My First Redux</h1>
        <hr />

        <div className="leadList">
          <LeadList
            avlList={this.state.leads}
            DeleteLead={this.handleRemoveLeads}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="leadForm">
          <LeadForm NewLead={this.handleAddToLeads} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you use state in LeadList component. Try to remove state from LeadList component. You don't need to manage multiple state's (this is important).

```
class LeadList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.props.avlList.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              {item.name} - {item.mobile} -{item.active ? "Active" : "Inactive"}
              -
              <div
                id={item.id}
                onClick={() => this.props.DeleteLead(item.id)}
                cursor="pointer"
              >
                X
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And fix `handleRemoveLeads` function in the parent (App) component.

```
handleRemoveLeads(lead_id) {
    console.log(" Leads list before fitler ..." + this.state.leads);

    // THIS IS NOT WORKING
    //let newFitleredLeads = remove(this.state.leads, lead_id);

    // BETTER SOLUTION
    let newFitleredLeads = this.state.leads.filter(item => item.id !== lead_id);

    this.setState({
      leads: newFitleredLeads
    });
    console.log(" Leads list after fitler ..." + this.state.leads);   
}
```

This should work fine.
Working example (without form): https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-kowalevski-rj5nj

Comment: It worked Very Well .. Thanks for Answer .. I want to know is List Rendering should always be Stateless ?   I also solved the issue by using  `getDerivedStateFromProps()`  ' in Lead List Component  , Which one is best method

Comment: @panindrakr not necessarily always stateless, it depends on how you plan your App. I personally avoid managing multiple states, because every state adds additional complexity to the App. This is the main reason for using redux, to have one single global state of the App. I think it's much easier to pass props to children components then use `getDerivedStateFromProps()`.